# How to get Javascript object value

Tags: javascript

Print off the var map

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(el), settings);
  console.log(map);
```

the output is

```
Ri {gm_accessors_: Object, zoom: 15, gm_bindings_: Object, center: Q, disableDefaultUI: true…}
Ab: Wh
D: W
De: rg
Fc: rg
I: W
Ja: yg
N: W
Re: rg
Se: rg
__e3_: Object
b: div#map
center: Q
controls: Array[14]
d: Qi
disableDefaultUI: true
e: W
features: W
gm_accessors_: Object
gm_bindings_: Object
keyboardShortcuts: false
l: rg
mapDataProviders: "Map data ©2013 Google"
mapTypeId: "roadmap"
mapTypes: Gg
mapUrl: "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=48.89376,2.33742&z=15&t=m&hl=en-US&mapclient=apiv3"
overlayMapTypes: yg
streetView: Qi
tilt: 0
tosUrl: "http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html"
wc: yg
zoom: 15
zoomControl: true
__proto__: c
```

I just wanted to get this div ID value `b: div#map`. `console.log(map.b)` doesn't print `div#map` is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome (or whatever browser you're using) is probably providing a condensed representation of the object at the point that you log `map`.  My guess is that `map.b` is returning the DOM element itself, but I can't tell unless you share what `console.log(map.b)` is returning.  If it is returning a DOM element that has an ID, then you could just call `map.b.id` to get what you're looking for.